# How would you say 'go round the houses' in a formal way?

Tags: phrases, expressions

I am writing a memo (quite formal) and I need to mention that the attitudes in the previous meeting were really offtopic, the team didn't focus on the important matters.

Were it informal writing I would use **go all round the houses**. Which expression would be adequate for a formal context?

Comment: Why not say that "the attitudes in the previous meeting where really off topic"?

Comment: Because that's a little too direct.

Comment: Are you the leader of this team? If so, then you *should* be direct.

Comment: It is not about a position, it is about directness, but thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could say **unproductive** or **unfocused**.

Not so long ago, you could have used the word **inappropriate**, but that is now a suggestive catch-all for anything awkward, lewd, rude or lecherous.

Comment: heh great point on "inappropriate" ..

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word **prevaricate**.

> ### verb
>
> [no object]
>
> Speak or act in an evasive way:
>
> ‘he seemed to prevaricate when journalists asked pointed questions’

For your specific scenario I suppose the phrase *"I noticed a fair amount of prevarication at our previous meeting"* or something similar would be appropriate.

Comment: I agree with this answer as the technically correct one, but I think given other comments by the asker that it would be too direct, as it is fairly unambiguous. What they actually seemed to want is a politic way of expressing the sentiment, not the correct formal word.